# How to make a sublist refers to his original ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, reference

I have a homework to do in java about ArrayList and Generics types.

I have 2 classes :
-> CoupeDeA
-> TableauPartiel

CoupeDeA is just a describer from where to where an array is cut.
(It contains only two private integer variables "begin" and "end")

TableauPartiel is the class where the ArrayList is.

My problem is I need to create a method in TableauPartiel like this :

```java
public TableauPartiel<E> coupe(CoupeDeA coupe)
```

And the TableauPartiel returned needs to be a reference of my intial TableauPartiel. Example :

```java
Integer[] arr = {8,7,6,5};
TableauPartiel<E> tab = new TableauPartiel<>(arr);

TableauPartiel<E> tab2 = tab.coupe(1,3);
tab2.set(1,45);
```

This code is supposed to set 45 at index 1 of my tab2 and at the same time set 45 at index 2.

But I tried many different ways and I managed to get the sublist, but it is not pointing to my original ArrayList.

For example, I tried something like this :

```java
private ArrayList<E> tableau;
...
public TableauPartiel<E> coupe(Coupe coupe)
            throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
    if (coupe.getBegin() >= 0 && coupe.getEnd() <= tableau.size()) {

        TableauPartiel<E> tab = new TableauPartiel<>((E[]) new Object[coupe.getEnd()-coupe.getBegin()]);

        for (int i = 0; i < coupe.getEnd()-coupe.getBegin(); ++i) {
            tab.set(i, this.get(coupe.getBegin()+i));
        }

        return tab;

    } else {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

How can I do to get a sublist which refers to his original ArrayList?

I've found a solution for my code with the subList method and by switching the signature of my ArrayList to List but my teacher doesn't want us to use subList finally.
Here is my code with the subList method :

```java
TableauPartiel<E> tab;

if (coupe.getDebut() >= 0 && coupe.getFin() <= taille()) {
    if (coupe.getFin() == -1)
        tab = new TableauPartiel<>(tableau.subList(coupe.getDebut(),taille()));
    else
        tab = new TableauPartiel<>(tableau.subList(coupe.getDebut(),coupe.getFin()));

     return tab;
    } else {
    throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }
}
```

Comment: We really need to see the code that makes the sublist.  It's pretty simple, but you should show us how you did it.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-

Comment: Yes, I tried with the sublist but when I return my new TableauPartiel with the sublist, it doesn't refers to the original ArrayList, when I modify my subList, it does not modify my ArrayList.

Comment: I added my current method which create a sublist but it doesn't refers to my ArrayList tableau.

Comment: Yes it does. It says so in the Javadoc. What is your reason for thinking otherwise?

Comment: No it's ok i solved my problem with the subList method but my teacher just said we can't use it for this work. He actually wants us to do the same work as subList but without the method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few small things first:

- stick to English words in your code. Especially in names of classes, functions, variables, etc - names have to reveal intentions (without Google Translate). Best not to obtain a bad habit by letting yourself do otherwise.
- I am not so sure how your `Coupe` is expected to work (is `0` a legal min number or `1`?) but `coupe.getEnd() <= tableau.size()` might get out of hand

Now my suggestion for the solution:

I suggest you modify your `TableauPartiel` class to have `start` and `end` integer fields in addition to `private ArrayList<E> tableau;` reference you already have. Maybe add a new 'copy constructor' accepting an instance of 
`TableauPartiel` (from which you can copy reference to `tableau`) and two `int` values indicating which part of the original `tableau` you can use (trick here is to also look at `start` and `end` values of the object you're 'sublisting' from). That way, when you're calling `#coupe` you can check for validity of the input numbers (as you already do) and simply return a new `TableauPartiel` object with a reference to `this` and method params - `start` and `end` values. Add some indexes manipulation logic using those `start` and `end` to whatever methods your `TableauPartiel` has and you should be good to go.

Comment: I tried your solution, it doesn't works, I do have my sublist but it doesn't refers to my original ArrayList. I have found a solution for my problem with the method subList but my teacher doesn't want us to use this method... I can send you my method with the sublist if it can helps to understand much better my problem. 
Otherwise, for the english/french words in my code, I actually do code my work in French but I translated some words here just for the understanding. But it's good to remind me about this :)

Comment: Finally, I just misunderstood what you suggested me to do. It was exactly what I needed to do. Thanks you a lot ! :D

Comment: I am glad it worked. Also, be careful with the collection resizing - if you need to add or remove elements to that original collection and want the values to keep changing respectively in the sublists you need to add a separate mechanism to maintain correct `start` and `end` values. For example you could keep a list of references to sublist objects in the original object, so that when a change is occured you can make proper indexes updates in the sublist references. The suggestion would be then to make objects of Sublist type immutable (have a separate type).